# jQuery - button click triggers ajax calls but let them finish one after another in the order they were triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a button that on click triggers an ajax request. Suppose I click it `n` times and `n` ajax calls are triggered but I want them to finish in the order they were triggered.

Html:

```
<button  id="btn" value="Click Me">Click Me</button>
<div id="items">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
       method:"POST",
      url:"action.php",
      success:function(response){
       $("#items").after('<div class="demo">Demo Item</div>');
      }
    });
});
```

**Explanation:**

I insert an element i.e.  `div` with class `demo` to `items` in the  success callback. But the ajax call may take some time to finish. So I am thinking to insert the element before starting the ajax call so that the user sees that data is inserted instantly.

So if the user clicks the button 3 times, 3 `div`s will be inserted instantly but the ajax calls may not yet finish. And I  want to finish the calls in the order they were created.

**Q1)** How to achieve that ?

**Q2)** Is that a good idea ? User may leave the page even before the ajax calls are finished. How to handle that critical situation then ?

Comment: Do you really care what order they finish, or just that the output show in the same order that they were started?

Comment: The client can't control the order that things finish on the server.

Comment: Have you considered keeping a state of whether there is a current ajax request and simply disabling the button if one is in progress?

Comment: You seem to be missing `#` in ` $("items")` should be ` $("#items")`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, fixed that

Comment: @jared.g, that is a solution , but any better way ?

Comment: @Barmar, finishing order is  not necessary actually. But if 2 ajax calls begin executing at the same time then some session variable may not be taken in consideration from the prevous call, right ?

Comment: @Ahmed You may look into promises??.. I really don't have a good suggestion, this is just the nature of async programming.. either you take control of your state or you don't care about the order of events

Comment: That's correct. So either the server scripts should allow them to execute in either order, or you shouldn't send the second AJAX request until the first has completed.

Comment: You can que your ajax calls and proceed with the next one when the previous one is finished or disable the button till you have handled the ajax call and enable it again.

Comment: if i understood correctly, you need to add an empty div component (like a blurred placeholder) on ajax request and populate it with information once the callback kicks in ?

Comment: @grumpy, how to do the queue thing ?

Comment: You can't finish call in order they where created, but you can control result display it in the order they were created... Use a counter, create a hidden div or span with the id that contains this counter and then, when ajax is finished, fill this span or div with the result and unhide it (this is an idea)

Comment: @Dani, I cound instead add the `div` in callback

Comment: Yeah, is another option :P